# how to get id to create objects by id with django-rest-framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

> Blockquote

Organization get id 5 and can create department with org id and get display Department by id org

> Blockquote

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.